# How to paginate a table using the DataTables pagination plugin

Tags: jquery, pagination, jquery-plugins, cdn

I consider myself a noob when it comes to client side scripting so I'm probably making a rookie mistake here.

I want to paginate my table using the DataTables.net Jquery plugin. Everything I have tried makes no changes to the table whatsoever. Here is the latest code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Striped Rows</h2>
  <p>The .table-striped class adds zebra-stripes to a table:</p>            
  <table id="tabledata" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>Dooley</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>scr="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"</script>
<script>scr="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"</script>

<script>
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#tabledata').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

By the way, I'm using Flask to deliver the page, but I don't think that would matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination happens in Datatables by default. The issue is because the `script` and `link` elements you've added to your HTML are not using the correct syntax.

Specifically, the attribute is `src` not `scr`, the `>` goes at the end of the tag, and the CSS file needs to be included using `<link />`, not `<script />`. These elements also need to be placed either within the `<head>`, or just before `</body>`.

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
  <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#tabledata').DataTable();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Striped Rows</h2>
    <p>The .table-striped class adds zebra-stripes to a table:</p>
    <table id="tabledata" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>John</td>
          <td>Doe</td>
          <td>john@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Mary</td>
          <td>Moe</td>
          <td>mary@example.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>July</td>
          <td>Dooley</td>
          <td>july@example.com</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```